# Show 404 for protected pages (with no address change)

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I've set **404** error page in `.htaccess` and it works fine.

```
ErrorDocument 404 somedir/404.php
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to show that page when user with no privileges tries to access some pages.

Ok, what have I tried so far?

Logic says if I redirect user to some non-existing page that will trigger **404 server response**, or I can just redirect him to `404.php`. Correct, that works.

```
header ("location: /404.php");
exit;
```

That way URL changes from one, user asked for, to (in this example) `http://www.mydomain.com/404/php`. I don't want to change it! I want user to see address he requested, no matter is that page protected or doesn't exist at all.

Course, I can work around and load `404.php` but that makes headache to me because of way how its template engine works. There's entire philosophy of how that tplEngine controlls templates and I'll leave that as "Plan B" if needed.

Is there any easy way to do that with no complicated work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the document header to show a 404 error.

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
```

After that, you can load the 404.php page with file_get_contents(). The URL will stay the same.

Comment: wait a second, you just gave me an idea. give me some time to try it.

Comment: Yes, that works. I have tried that earlier but somehow I made typo mistake using that same header. It works now. Thanks a million.

Comment: May be I misunderstood the question but this will just return 404 status but won't show custom 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `header` function you can include `404.php` and return custom status:

```
include ( "404.php" );
exit;
```

And from `404.php` have this:

```
http_response_code( 404 );
```

Comment: Yes, that's my "plan B" but look. That 404.php isn't just a simple script. It loads a lot of information about user, selected language (interface), skin, etc. Dozens of very same things (scripts) are also loaded by that page which eventually has to show 404.php. There are a lot of scripts called by `include_once` and `require_once`and I just don't want to go through all of them and change it. It's very complicated structure (+ multi-server). That's why I said it will be "Plan B". Anyway, thanks for your response.

Comment: Have to upvote this as working example in case some people use simple error pages. Thanks a lot.